# What would be my total saving with an increasing and regular yearly deposit after 30 years?

Tags: savings, calculation, compound-interest

Let's say I deposit $50,000 into the bank and in the first year I put in an installment of 5,000 and the interest is calculated monthly at 7%. In the second year, all is the same except for my yearly installment, it is increased by $500 to $5,500. Year 3 's installment is $6,000. Year 4 's installment is 6,500. The yearly installment keeps increasing by $500 every year for 30 years (including the first year's installment of $5,000) because my income increases so I can save more. What would be my total saving by the end of the 30th year? How did you calculate it? What formulas did you use?

Comment: Is this a homework question? We need you to show some effort. Please edit the question and show your progress in solving the problem and where specifically you are having trouble.

Comment: Because the contribution increases every year, I don't think there's one simple equation.  You've got to use 30 equations.

Comment: @BenMiller, no it's not. I was just sitting back and thinking about how much my future saving would if I followed such method of saving. I already know how to calculate compound interest and compound interest with regular exact installment. But I was just wondering if my salary increased every year, I would be able to deposit more into my saving account and so comes the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have uneven cash flow, you have to break the problem down into pieces, enough that each set of cash flows is even.  In this case, the cash flow for each year is even, and given there are 30 years, you'll need to solve each year for the future value at the end of that year, and use the result of that year as the starting value for the next year.  Then, you'll end up with the FV at +30 years.  [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/exam-guide/cfa-level-1/quantitative-methods/time-value-money-calculations.asp) has a guide that could be an intro to economics text.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use a spreadsheet. I wrote one some time ago for an article [Retirement Savings Ratio](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/retirement-savings-ratio/) and while it was written for a slightly different reason, it does exactly what you wish for. You enter your salary, % you will save, growth in salary each year and return on investment. The spreadsheet isn't protected, so it's easy to edit out the features you don't want.